# How to combine 2 redirections in one, https + removing trailing slashes of url?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

My htaccess actually looks like :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com(.)*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z/\ -]+)(?:&([0-9a-zA-Z&=_\ -]+))?$ index.php?action=$1&$2 [L]
# $1 : route name and framework parameters
# $2 : classic $_GET parameters (&param=value)
```

It redirects to https, then redirect to url without trailing slashes, then rewrite a clean url without index etc.

I would like to know, if I enter `http://www.example.com/somepage/`, how to redirect to `https://example.com/somepage` in a single redirection instead of multiple?

Comment: FYI please!! I just changed domain.com to `test.domain.com` as it was giving an error in editing in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know, if I enter `http://example.com/somepage/`, how to redirect to `https://example.com/somepage` in a single redirection instead of two?

You can use this single redirect rule for that:

```bash
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# add https, remove www and remove trailing slash in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ index.php?action=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, no I've got the too many redirections error. Can I abuse your kindness to ask you to add a rule for "www.", remove it if it is in url, together with the two other rules? Thanks for your time!

Comment: ok I have updated my answer. Note that this should be your complete .htaccess, there should be no other rule. Test it from a new browser or command line curl to avoid old cache.

Comment: Sorry, there's something wrong in 1 case. If I come from url domain.com, I have an internal redirection to domain.com/home that doesn't work in this case. But if I come directly from domain.com/home, no problem. The code is simply if($_GET['action']==NULL) redirect ...

Comment: Where is that rule that internally rewrites to /home? And please clarify what exactly is not working?

Comment: in index.php, I have this line of code :  if(!isset($_GET['action'])) {exit(header("location: $this->home"));} where $this->home is a framework attribute with value "/home". if I type in url bar "domain.com/home", all works fine, but "domain.com", I've no redirection to "domain.com/home" but instead the too many redirections error.

Comment: That is not internal rewrite, it as an external redirection which is happening in  your code. Note that rules run before and php code runs later. Also note that trailing slash is automatically added to a directory path by mod_dir module. Is home a real directory?

Comment: Also you should open Chrome developer window while testing with caching disabled to see what redirects are happening

Comment: No, home is note e real directory, it's the value of url parameter action, that execute the controller that display the page.

Comment: Ok then take my suggestion in previous comment to trace it better

Comment: I have lots of redirections to domain.com/ (with a trailing slash at the end). I guess it causes an infinite loop but don't understand why.

Comment: If htaccess rule is removing trailing slash and your code keeps adding it back somewhere then there will be a redirect loop for sure. My answer is purely from htaccess context and it is properly tested and working rules that I have posted here.